# How can I make a circuit that amplifies and mixes, at different ratios, the sound signals coming out of two different instruments

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, sound

Do I need to use 2 sound sensors to detect the sound signals?
If yes, can the sensors be connected directly in the circuit? or do I need to use an Arduino card and program it? 
Instead of the the sensors can I use small microphones and a loud speaker for the output?
The entry of the sound signals to the circuit is essentially what I cannot solve.

Please note that I am in 2nd grade of Licence in Electrical-Electronics Engineering and this is my first homework. So I think that it has to be a simple thing. We studied about OP AMP s too and I think I need to use 2 (a summing and an inverting). What do you think?

Comment: An audio mixer (a "summing amplifier") is not really too hard for a second grade student of EE, to be honest.

Comment: You should also look closely at your assumption that an inverting stage is needed. Can your ear tell the difference? But it's good that you have thought of it, since the answer may require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this is a homework assignment, I doubt that you need to be concerned with where the audio signals come from — you can just assume that they are voltage sources with regard to the design of your mixer.

Comment: Yes, most of my colleagues used voltage sources but I wanted to answer the question as it is.
I used a 2 jacks and a loud speaker
Thank you everybody for trying to help me